# Infimum of Binomial Confidence Interval Coverage Probability

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval, binomial-distribution

Let $X \sim \text{Binomial}(n,p)$. Let $\hat{p} = X/n$ be the estimator for $p$. Let the confidence interval for unknown $p$ be
$$
\hat{p} \pm z_{\alpha/2}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}.
$$
I am trying to find the infimum of the coverage probability for fixed $n$, where the infimum is taken over a subset of the range of $(0,1)$. That is, I'm trying to find
$$
\inf_{p \in (a,b) }P\left[\hat{p} - z_{\alpha/2}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} < p < \hat{p} + z_{\alpha/2}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} \right]
$$
assuming $0<a<b<1$.

My intuition is that the infimum occurs when $p$ is equal to one of the endpoints, because it will have the smallest width, but I can't show why. Probably $a$ if it's closer to $0$ than $b$ is closer to $1$.

Another hunch of mine is that if I could write the probability as the cdf of some random variable, I could find the infimum more easily because cdf's are always non-decreasing. But even if this was possible, this random variable has weird support.

Another thing I've noticed is that probability above is equal to 
$$
P\left[\hat{p} - z_{\alpha/2}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}} < p < \hat{p} + z_{\alpha/2}\ \sqrt{\frac{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})}{n}}, 0 < X < n \right].
$$

Also, I'm trying to make my way through [this](http://www.stat.nctu.edu.tw/hwang/12_SS_2007.pdf), which seems to be relevant.

Comment: See Proposition 1 in the following paper, though this gives you the lim inf:  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ss/1009213286